# Retry a task in heterogeneous intervals in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, email, job-scheduling

In my Spring Boot app, I am trying to send Email using AWS SES service.

If the Email sending fails, I want to retry 3 times:

- Initial after 60 seconds
- After 1 hour
- After 4 hours

Once Email sending is a success, I update state in a DB.

This microservice receives a large number of requests (~1M per hour) so the solution has to scale.

I thought of 2 solutions:

- Implement a `Thread` which will execute email sending process and if it fails, it will `sleep` for an interval. But that doesn't sound to be a scalable solution.
- Implement a `Scheduler` which runs in some `interval`, fetch failed Emails from DB and retry them.

The problem is AWS SES process takes about 8 seconds to construct a connection, send email, get the results. If there are a large number of emails that have failed, 2 scheduler threads might even overlap.

What can be the optimal solution for this problem?

Comment: Kafka? And I'm required to write something more in order to post this comment.

Comment: Ok, so I was already using RabitMQ for my project and now I found that I can delay messages there as well : https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/. Bad that I didn't found this earlier.